# actual argument Date cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Javac says to me:

```
error: method nextTimeAfter in class Task cannot be applied to given types;
if (processed.nextTimeAfter(start) != null
^
required: int
found: Date
reason: actual argument Date cannot be converted to int by method invocation conversion
```

but in my task, argument is Date, not int:

```
public Date nextTimeAfter(Date current) {
  // may return null or DATE
}
```

Here is a code-caller:

```
public static Iterable<Task> incoming(Iterable<Task> tasks, Date start,
            Date end) {
        if (start.before(end))
            return tasks;
        LinkedList<Task> result = new LinkedList<Task>();
        for (Task processed : tasks) {
            if (processed.nextTimeAfter(start) != null
                    && processed.nextTimeAfter(start).before(end)) {
                result.add(processed);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

And in addition, Task class

```
public class Task {
    private Date time;
    private Date startTime;
    private Date repeatInterval;
    private Date endTime;

    //...getters-setters

    public Date nextTimeAfter(Date current) {
        if (current == null)
               throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument <current> is NULL");
        if (!isActive() || (!isRepeated() && current.after(getTime())))
            return null;
        Date result = getStartTime();
        while (result.after(current)) {
            Date temp = (Date) result.clone();
            temp.setTime(temp.getTime() + getRepeatInterval().getTime());
            if (temp.after(getEndTime()))
                return null;
            result.setTime(result.getTime() + getRepeatInterval().getTime());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

It's quite strange, why it works so. Eclipse doesn't show any errors, but compiler swears(

Comment: processed is an foreach's local value of iterator's current item;

Comment: Show us the code of `Task` class. The `nextTimeAfter` method you've posted doesn't seem to match with the exception thrown

Comment: more importantly how are you compiling the whole thing? I mean what's your command. Did you, in the past, have a method nextTimeAfter(int x)? My far fetched guess is that you have an old compiled version of Task with the old method and you're trying to use that instead of recompiling Task. But as I said it's far fetched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by what you added and said until now I will go with my previous hunch: while compiling the project (are you simply doing "javac" or something else?) you are not recompiling the Task class and the compiler is using some old version in which that method accepts an int and not a Date (as I asked: did you have such a version?).

The classpath and the compilation options must be properly set in Eclipse therefore it does not complaint.

To fix it make sure you recompile the Task class before compiling your other code.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is actually saying that `nextTimeAfter` expects an `int`:

> ```
> required: int <-- what java expected
> found: Date   <-- what you did
> ```

You passed a `date`.  You should be passing an `int`.

You can call something like `start.getTime()/1000` and convert to int

Comment: OP posted in the question that he wants to pass Date as the argument and that his method's signature is taking a Date as one. Hence he's perplexed why the compiler wants an int.

Comment: yep, ive understood the error, but why it expect int, while nextTimeAfter's prototype is Date nextTimeAfter(Date current)?